# Android : database connection

Tags: php, android

I have already finished my app, it works fine on the emulator but when I publish my database on a host it shows me an error connecting to the base.

-Here is a run in the emulator:
[LOGIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VREgb.png)

[PROFIL][2]

-here is a run after the publication of the database:
[LOGIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz2vN.jpg)

-Finally here's the PHP code authentication:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("sql*****.byethost22.com","b22_177*****","chahi****");

mysql_select_db("b22_1*****_muo"); 

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

$cin =$_REQUEST['num_cin'];

$pass =$_REQUEST['mot_passe'];

$sql=mysql_query("select * from personne, enseignant 

      where personne.cin = enseignant.cin

           AND  enseignant.cin='$cin' and  personne.mot_de_passe =     '$pass'"); while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

 $output[]=$row;

 print(json_encode($output)); 

?>
```

Comment: Remote access to host database is probably disabled. Can't you just use localhost in `mysql_connect` if your php files are on same host as database?

Comment: how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: how can i solve this problem ?